# How to create an empty 2d array in javascript? below is an example of what I want to create

Tags: javascript

How to create an empty 2d array in javascript? below is an example of what I want to create

```
[[1, a, c], [2, d, e], [3, w, e]];
```

I just want to create a empty 2d array. Note I dont know any of the values and I dont know the size of array:

var a= [][] ??

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var a = [[], [], []];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should create a new array, and then push three elements that make up a similar content of what you requested (string values instead of variables).

```
var a = [];
a.push([1, 'a', 'c']);
a.push([2, 'd', 'e']);
a.push([3, 'w', 'e']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to create a new, completely blank, 2D Array:

```
var array = [[]];
```